# Filter rows of pandas dataframe with column condition, but the name of the column is supposed to be partial match

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have data like this

[image]

I want to apply column condition to filter out the rows based on the condition `WinningPoints > 40`.
I can get this done by using
`dataframe[(dataframe.WinningPoints > '40')]`

However, I would like to pass a partial label in the column tag and maybe use regex to match the entire string,something like this

dataframe[(dataframe.**WinningPo.*** > '40')]

I want to print all the columns.

How can this be done?  Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: Use [code fences](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) to format your code. [Test formatting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3122/formatting-sandbox) before posting questions.

Answer (score 0):

After going through the pandas documentation, I didn't find pancea. But, you can use the filter function in pandas to get a subset dataframe like this:

```
df.filter(regex='WinningPo.*',axis = 1)
```

And then apply your condition for each column

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.

However, with this method will trim all other columns and prints only the one matched column. Here I want to print other columns as well.